# Plural vs singular word in URL and title tag

Tags: seo, url, keywords

Please advise which is better for a page with multiple property listings:

```
example.com/apartments-to-let/area
```

vs

```
example.com/apartment-to-let-area
```

Isn't the plural better since it is an accurate description of what is on the page? Singular versions of my search terms have higher traffic.

Comment: Yes, the first example is better. Please see my [other answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/115295/how-should-i-construct-a-site-so-that-the-url-is-meaningful-for-the-user-and-big) for a suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Once again, please think about logic and users before SEO. Therefore, the plural version is better of course, you specified in the question by yourself.

Moreover, search engines know recognizing words in singular or plural, that's why there is no difference regarding SEO between these two URLs. Thus, you can easily choose the logic one.

Comment: I agree with Zistoloen. Opt for making it user friendly over trying to make it better for SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Google confirms that they do treat singular and plural words differently and serve different search results.

Here is Google's John Mueller explaining so: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7m-cd8XXovQ&t=1526s